# No C++ compiler found in MATLAB using mex

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to write C++ programs and integrate it with MATLAB using mex interface.
I wrote mex -setup command on MATLAB and this was the result
Select a compiler:

[0] None

I have Visual Studio 2010 installed on a Windows 7 64 bit PC with MATLAB R2009b installed (64bit). I read somewhere visual studio 2010 should have 64 bit compiler installed which is done.
Can some one help me out please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be related to the fact that cl.exe is not in your %PATH ?
Try fixing your PATH using the Options Panel on "My Computer" and try again

Answer (score 3):

You need to install both Visual Studio 2008 and the corresponding Windows SDK: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/compilers/R2009b/win64.html

Visual Studio 2010 isn't supported by R2009b. R2010a is the first that supports VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to compile the mex-file directly on the Matlab's command line.

An alternative would be to compile the mex-file from Visual Studio. You might be interested in the following procedure

[Compiling mex files with Visual Studio](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/?s=mex)

which has been tested with Visual Studio 2010, Matlab 2010a and for an Intel 64bit target machine.

There is also a Visual Studio 2010 project you can download and modify with your own configuration parameters, if needed.