# Matlab Mex file compile

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm trying to compile a mex file to use socket connection within matlab. The problem is that it is always saying that I don't have sdk or compiler installed. But I have installed visual studio 2010 express, visual studio 2012 express, visual studio 2012 professional and nothing is changing the error. Also I have installed the sdk. Is there anything that I could try? The matlab version is R2012b and I'm using windows 7, 64 bits.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe VS2012 Express does not come with a 64-bit compiler by default, so will not work for MEXing from 64-bit MATLAB. HAve you tried 32-bit MATLAB?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [gnumex](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnumex/), which lets you access the mingw compilers on Windows. It works with [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) which is the 64 bit version of [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/). You have to install the mingw compiler suite, then run gnumex in Matlab to tell it where mingw is and set it up.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Visual Studio 2012 is only supported on the latest R2013a. Use VS2010 for your MATLAB version.

In addition, the Express editions of VS do not contain 64-bit compilers. You need to either get the Professional edition, or download the free Windows SDK.

See the list of [supported compilers](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/) for more information

Comment: Here the corresponding page for 64-bit R2012b: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2012b/win64.html

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to compile the mex-file directly on the Matlab's command line.

An alternative would be to compile the mex-file from Visual Studio. You might be interested in my answer to

[No C++ compiler found in MATLAB using mex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281871/no-c-compiler-found-in-matlab-using-mex/17920144#17920144)

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `mex -setup` to tell MATLAB *which* compiler you want to use?

See [this page on Building MEX-Files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-mex-files.html) for more information

Comment: yeah, I used mex -setup. What I got was that I do not have the compiler...but I have visual studio 2012 professional...

Answer (score 0):

May be this link wil be useful for you
http://support.brainvoyager.com/available-tools/52-matlab-tools-bvxqtools/339-how-to-get-a-64-bit-compiler-under-windows-to-use-with-matlab.html