# Speeding up Matlab optimizations by CUDA

Tags: matlab, optimization, cuda, numerical

I was wondering if I can improve the speed of my simulations with CUDA in Matlab by simply breaking up the loop into GPU-threads.

So far I have done the loops with mclapply in R, but I was wondering, if I could **speed it up in Matlab with CUDA**? (Nvidia Gtx 650 ti boost)

Here is a **simplified example** of what I'm doing:
I have a dataset of dim 2000x9 and I want to run at least 250 loops with moving data window (ca. 1500 rows), these loops are independent thus perfect for parallel computation.

**Example of loop:** Take the first 1500 rows. Some magic with the whole dataset (1500x9). Calculate univariate function on each column (do 9times operation on 1500x1) and then run minimization problem with a certain loss function for each column (do 9times operation on 1500x1).
(inbetween I'm also working with all columns, so I cannot separate the columns in different threads)

**My idea:**
If I would be running each loop in different GPU-thread? Does it make sense to do such a hard computational problem in single GPU core? (for illustration, 1 loop takes ca. 300seconds on i7 3770k on 1 core)

I know that single GPU threads are much slower compared to CPU, but if all loops will be running simultaneously? Especially since each loop takes so long once its given data, so feeding the data to GPU will take only insignificant portion of overall time.

Important note: I'm a very lousy "programmer", and what I plan is just splitting the for loop (i in 1:250) in function of variable i and passing this to GPU.

Comment: If each element's result is independent of any other elements' result, then they can be computed in parallel. Otherwise you will need a reduction algorithm to at least use some parallellism.

Comment: yes, they are independent. My question was more like if it's easily implementable? (Can I just pass the data to function and the wrapper will put the results back together like with mclapply?)       and second part, if it makes sense for the way GPU works, since the GPU-threads would do a rather complex computations / run demanding functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three main issues related to the fact that each thread should perform a whole minimization process (which kind of Matlab minimization routine are you currently using? `fminunc`? `fminsearch`? `minFunc`?).

1. Minimizations can be demanding in terms of needed temporary variables. This could limit the performance of your algorithm due to the need of storing temporaries and transacting them, for example, with global memory, depending of course on how do you mean to implement it.
2. You should also carefully take into account thread synchronization, since the time needed for accomplishing the minimization process could change from thread to thread.
3. Matlab has very effective optimization routines, whose performance are generally difficult (but, of course, not impossible) to replicate by a custom implementation. In my experience, Matlab's `fminunc` is more effective than the Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno equivalent routine provided by the NAG. So, if you are trying to translate one of the above optimization routines, then you could end up by a less satisfactory result.

I have faced many optimization problems using Matlab accelerated with CUDA and my "gold rule" is to use one of the Matlab's optimization routines and accelerate the solution of the direct problem (calculation of the functional) and the functional gradient by purposely written CUDA codes interfaced with Matlab by mex-files. Take into account that especially the gradient needs to (and can) be accelerated since the calculation of the functional derivative by finite differences are independent and require the invokation of as many functional computation routines as is the number of optimization parameters.

**EDIT**
Suppose that I have to optimize the objective functional `objfun`. What I'm doing is to code `objfun` in CUDA with a mex-file interface, compiling it by `nvcc` and then linking it under Matlab.

As I'm using Matlab 2010, the CUDA function is compiled by `nvcc` and transformed in C++ code by the command

```
system(sprintf('nvcc -I"%s/extern/include" --cuda "mexfun.cu" --output-file "mexfun.cpp"', matlabroot));
```

and then linked to Matlab by

```
mex -I/opt/cuda/include -L/opt/cuda/lib -lcudart mexfun.cpp
```

as suggested in [Compiling CUDA C/C++ mex code under linux](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/261866).

Then, when using, for example, `fminunc(@mexfun,...)`, Matlab will optimize the objective functional and each evaluation of it will be performed (and thus accelerated) on the GPU. When analytically available, I'm also coding the gradient calculation by the same approach, since finite differences used to evaluate the gradient can significantly slow down the whole optimization process.

For Matlab 2013 and Windows systems, see [Creating mex files from CUDA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104884/creating-mex-files-from-cuda-code).

**EDIT** Structure of mexfun.cu (objective function)

```
// Do not change the function name (`mexFunction`) and the function arguments (`nlhs`, `plhs`, ...). 
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])

{
    /* Maps Matlab's pointers to the input variables to CUDA pointers */
    double* input_1     = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    double* input_2     = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);

    /* Recovers the size of the input matrices */
    int dimx = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    ...         
    int dimu = mxGetM(prhs[3]);         

    /* Memory allocations on the host */
    cuDoubleComplex* hfoo = (cuDoubleComplex *)malloc(sizeof(cuDoubleComplex)*dimx);
    ...

   /* Memory allocations on the device */
   cuDoubleComplex* dfoo; cudaMalloc((void*)&d_Kernel_Matrix,dimx*sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
   ...

  /* Memory transfer from host to device */
  cudaMemcpy(dfoo,hfoo,dimx*sizeof(cuDoubleComplex),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  ....

  /* Kernel launch */
  dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE_X,BLOCK_SIZE_Y);
  Kernel_To_Be_Launched <<<dimGrid,dimBlock >>>(hfoo,dfoo,dimx);

 /* Copy the results from device to host */ cudaMemcpy(hfoo,dfoo,dimx*sizeof(cuDoubleComplex),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


 /* Passing the output matrices to MATLAB */
 plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,dimu,mxCOMPLEX);
 double* hfoo_re = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
 double* hfoo_im = mxGetPi(plhs[0]);

 /* Freeing host memory */
 free(hfoo);
 ...

 /* Freeing device memory */
 cudaFree(dfoo);
```

}

Comment: I haven't thought about routine yet (in R I'm using nlminb "Unconstrained and box-constrained optimization using PORT routines.") And I certainly don't want to rewrite the optimization routines. I lack both knowledge and experience. ---- What I wanted to do is to push each loop to different thread (complete optimization, calculation, matlab functions everything - no sending data back until it's finished). There will be no synchronization (I'll run all loops at once, since I have more CUDA cores than loops I need).

Comment: **I was wondering whether this can be faster (running all 250loops at once) than doing this "sequentially" with i7 on 8 cores.**  (Since recoding the routine from R to Matlab will be time demanding)

Comment: In the post you mention (or, at least, I understand so) that you would like to implement an entire loop, so including the minimization routine. It is not clear to me how do you mean to avoid reimplementations of the minimization process. But anyway, it is very difficult to answer with a _yes_ or _no_ to your question, as many elements are missing (see the answer by Novak).

Comment: Yes, I was wrong - I was hoping that I can just ship whole code to the gpu and it will take care of it (the same way mclapply uses multiple cpu cores in R). But what you are suggesting about improving optimizations is interesting. Are there any examples available? I wasn't able to find any.

Comment: Thank you! I have just a few questions to that: 1, Did you mean rather 'fminunc(@mexfun,...)' ? 2, So matlab optim routine doesn't evaluate the objective sequentially? it just ships the grid of arguments to the objective, thus if you code the objective in CUDA, it will distribute the various computations to different threads?  I hope I'm not asking to much, but could you maybe send me any example of such a objective function, so I have something to start with? When I google example it's usually done for very different purposes. Anyway, thank you! This was incredibly helpful!

Comment: @AnimMina Yes exactly. The calculation of the objective function will be performed on the device, and Matlab's `fminunc` will use its results. I have also fixed the `mexfun` mistake and I have added an example of CUDA objective function calculation. I hope it is useful. If so, please accept my answer (provided that Novak does not mind :-) ). Enjoy Matlab accelerated by CUDA! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would not consider myself an expert in CUDA (at all), but I have been using it extensively for the past little while.  My guess is that while you may indeed get some speed-up, it is hard to tell how much without the detailed knowledge of the problem that only you have, *and probably not without some effort*.  Which is to say, you probably can't just "throw it over the wall," so to speak and hope that the CUDA compiler will catch all the pieces.

My immediate concerns would be related to memory management and bus traffic, as CUDA has very strict rules for memory usage.  While the compiler will generally keep things chugging along as best it can, performance *will* degrade if you use the memory and bus inefficiently.

Specifically, in order to get good performance, you want to load pieces of your problem into the shared memory of the various streaming multiprocessors.  The available shared memory to an SM on modern cards is only 48K.  You describe your problem in chunks of 1500 x 9 (floats, I assume) which is already more than 48K.  Moreover, the shared memory on an SM is used by *all* the processors on an SM.  If your problem takes up all 48K of an SM, then most of that SM will sit idle.

So that sounds bad.  But, if there is a way that you can compute the answer to those 1500 x 9 chunks in smaller pieces and recombine, then you may have a candidate for a GPU approach.  Some creativity is often required.

**But I emphasize, this is only one concern.**  It is the one that jumped out at me, as being similar to the issue I'm wrestling with for another application.

JackOLantern raises others, and there are also read/write patterns, etc.

Comment: thank you. Now I see that I wouldn't be able to code it efficiently, maybe I can still use some gpu power when doing the optimizations as JackOlantern suggested.